# Name of JS plugin that is being used in the Google Nexus Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to find out what the jquery control being used on the Google Nexus website is called: http://www.google.com/intl/all/nexus/5/

Basically as you scroll down the website, the image background changes to a new one. Its not really lazy loading.

It is also used here:http://www.flipkart.com/motorola/motox?otracker=ts_motorola_explore_motox

I can roll my own based on just manipulating z-indexes and scrolling sections on the website, but I would really like to know what this is called.

Comment: I don't think Google would use a plugin, they probably rolled their own code, but try looking at the source code to figure out what they are doing.

Comment: Tried it, but not able to figure out what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that is a variant of [Parallax Scrolling](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique--net-27641)